# What is a proof of the Bianchi identity in the framework of Cartan's dg algebra connections?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, connections, differential-graded-algebras

For a general principal bundle (not necessarily Riemaninian),H Cartan developed a purely  dg algebra analog in which connection and curvature make sense. How can one prove the Bianchi identity in this formalism?